# CSS conflict. CSS changes my <select> class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I have a Laravel site with a form with a SELECT:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('admin/createactivity')}}">

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name') }}" />
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="activitytype">Type:</label>
        <select name="activitytype" class="form-control" value="{{ old('activitytype') }}">
            <option value="-">Select one</option>
            <?php
                foreach ($items as $name => $id) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $name . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" value="{{ old('description') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

It uses the Bootstrap classes `form-group` and `form-control` and they work pretty fine but when I join the page with this form, the SELECT suddenly changes it class from `form-control` to this:

```
<span class="jcf-select jcf-unselectable jcf-select-form-control">  
    <select name="activitytype" class="form-control jcf-reset-appearance" value="" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <option value="-">Select one</option>
        <option value="2">Aqua</option>
        <option value="1">HIIT</option>
    </select>
    <span class="jcf-select-text">
        <span class="">Select one</span>
    </span>
    <span class="jcf-select-opener"></span>
</span>
```

**This uses some JavaScript files as** '*jquery-1.11.3.min.js*', '*query.main.js*' and '*plugins.js*'. I think the problem is with this files, especially with 'plugins.js', but I don't know how to fix it.

The thing is that at the "beginning" of the load of the page, I can see the SELECT field correctly with the Bootstrap class and suddenly, after it loads completely the code, it changes.

Please, help.

Comment: The problem is visual or functional?

Comment: The problem is visual @ShlomiHaver.

Comment: I'm using plugins.js for some animations in the page. It is a template. Without 'plugins.js' its appearance is fixed @ZakariaAcharki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation of your code shows clearly that you're including **[`JCF - JavaScript Custom Forms`](https://www.psd2html.com/js-custom-forms/#demo)** library somewhere:

```
<span class="jcf-select jcf-unselectable jcf-select-form-control">  
_____________^__________^________________^
<select name="activitytype" class="form-control jcf-reset-appearance" value="" style=...>
________________________________________________^
```

Check inside your `plugins.js` and make sure to comment all `jcf` code or remove it,e.g :

```
jcf.replaceAll(); //comment this line if exist inside your ready function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Funny fact: there is no 'jcf' string in 'plugins.js'.

Comment: Ok. That was so easy and so obvious. Now i feel both fine and terribly bad. Thank you, sir.